# Nodejs sequelize search for multiple elements if request value exist

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Thanks in advance.

I am using POST method to search from database. But some request body values maybe not defined. I want to ignore these and search elements only if exist in POST method

```
function searchPhone(req, res) {
    return Phones.findAll({
        where: {
            description: { $like: '%' + req.body.description + '%', },
            simcard: [req.body.simcard| 1],  //if req.body.simcard exist in post then search if not skip 
        }
    })
    .then(fav => res.status(200).send(fav));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One of the way you can do is :**

```
function searchPhone(req, res) {

    let where = {};
    where['description'] = { $like: '%' + req.body.description + '%' };

    if(req.body.simcard) {
        where['simcard'] = [req.body.simcard| 1]
    }

    return Phones.findAll({ where }).then(fav => res.status(200).send(fav));
}
```

---

> Not sure about the below one , but I think it will work , give my
>   confirmation tomorrow

```
function searchPhone(req, res) {
    return Phones.findAll({
        where: {
            description: { $like: '%' + req.body.description + '%' },
            simcard: req.body.simcard ,  // <-- I think this will be ignored 
                                        //if simcard is not in req.body , please check the console for query
        }
    })
    .then(fav => res.status(200).send(fav));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also find this solution. It also works

```
Phones.findAll({
        where: {
            description: (req.body.description) ? { $like: '%' + req.body.description.trim() + '%' } : { $ne: null },
            simcart: (req.body.simcart) ? req.body.simcart : { $ne: null },
        }
    })
    .then(val => res.status(200).send(val));
```